# First page load doesn't have the most recent data (Nuxt 2 SSR + PWA)

Tags: nuxt.js, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm working with Nuxt 2 (SSR) using the [PWA Module](https://pwa.nuxtjs.org/).

I'm having an issue on first page load. The page is cached by the service worker, that means I do not have the most recent data on that first load. However, I have the most recent data if after the first load I navigate to another page and come back to the initial page.

[Network tab showing the initial page being served by the service worker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmD80.jpg)

I didn't find a way to configure the service worker to avoid caching the pages.
How can I configure the service worker to not cache "document" type request, or better, using the "Network First" strategy?

I've tried different workbox configuration and setting a custom `runtimeCaching` config but none of them work.
I'm pretty new with service workers so I would be very grateful if someone can help me.